# Создание домашнего UDP сервера на C++. Проблемы других компьютеров

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, asio

1. **Сервер**

   Есть самый простой клиент и сервер.  Сервер принимает  пакет, отправляет другой пакет и ждёт ещё одного, означающего успешное получение пакета клиентом.

   ```
   #include <array>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>

   int main()
   try{
       using namespace std;
       using namespace boost::asio;
       using namespace ip;

       io_service service;
       udp::socket socket{ service, { ip::udp::v4(), 9999u } };
       udp::endpoint client_ep;
       array<char, 100> recive_buffer;

       //First receive
       cout << "start recive\n";
       auto recived_length = socket.receive_from(buffer(recive_buffer), client_ep);
       cout << "message recived from: " + 
                client_ep.address().to_string() + ':' +
                to_string(client_ep.port()) + "\nrecived message: \"";
       cout.write(recive_buffer.data(), recived_length);
       cout << "\"";

       //Send
       cout << "\n\nsend answer\n";
       socket.send_to(buffer("ANSWER"s), client_ep);
       cout << "answer sent\n\n";

       //Second recive
       cout << "start recive 2\n";
       recived_length = socket.receive(buffer(recive_buffer));
       cout << "message recived\nrecived message: \"";
       cout.write(recive_buffer.data(), recived_length);
       cout << "\"";
   }
   catch (const std::exception& err)
   {
       std::cerr << err.what();
   }
   ```

   Я сделал forward-инг моего роутера на мой компьютер:

   [image: Экранный снимок конфигурации TP-Link]

   От чего на моём компьютере всё заработало.
2. **Клиент**

   Клиент отправляет пакет на сервер, а затем принимает другой пакет от сервера. Если приём успешен, то клиент отправляет ещё один пакет.

   ```
   #include <array>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <thread>
   int main()
   try{
       using namespace std;
       using namespace boost::asio;
       using namespace ip;

       io_service service;
       udp::socket socket{ service, udp::endpoint{udp::v4(), 9997 } };
       this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
       array<char, 64> recive_buffer;
       udp::endpoint server_ep{ address::from_string("100.71.188.14"s), 9999u };
       socket.send_to(buffer( "local address: "s + 
                           socket.local_endpoint().address().to_string() + 
                           ':' + std::to_string(socket.local_endpoint().port()))
                           ,server_ep);
       socket.receive(buffer(recive_buffer));
       socket.send_to(buffer("OK"s), server_ep);
   }
   catch (const std::exception& err)
   {
       std::cerr << err.what();
   }
   ```
3. **Работа**

   Сервер запущен на моём компьютере. Далее приведён вывод кода сервера для клиентов запущенных на разных компьютерах:

   - Клиент запущен на моём компьютере (там же где и сервер):

     > ```
     > C:\Users\effol\Desktop>test-server
     > start receive
     > message recived from: 100.71.188.14:63806
     > recived message: "local address: 0.0.0.0:63806"
     >
     > send answer
     > answer sent
     >
     > start recive 2
     > message recived
     > recived message: "OK"
     > C:\Users\effol\Desktop>
     > ```
   - Клиент запущен на компьютере друга 1:

     > ```
     > C:\Users\effol\Desktop>test-server
     > start recive
     > message recived from: 188.163.106.39:56120
     > recived message: "local address: 0.0.0.0:55404"
     >
     > send answer
     > answer sent
     >
     > start recive 2
     > ```
   - Клиент запущен на компьютере друга 2:

     > ```
     > C:\Users\effol\Desktop>test-server
     > start recive
     > ```

## Теперь вопросы

Почему на моём компьютере всё работает? Почему на компьютере друга 1 клиент не принимает сообщений с сервера? Почему на комьюптере друга 2 сервер даже не видит его сообщения?

Может быть это из-за фаерволла? Тогда как работают все другие приложения, типо скайпа или торрента илли баттл.нета. Подскажите господа продвинутые, в какую сторону копать, из-за чего так происходит, и почему с другими приложениями такого не происходит?

## Обновление вопроса

*(код клиента поправлен)*

Брандмауэр! Когда раньше я открывал сокет так:

```
udp::socket socket{ service, udp::endpoint{udp::v4(), 0} };
```

Брандмауэр не вызывал предложение, разрешить для этой программы всё то, что брандмауэр запрещает. Но когда я передаю в конструкторе конкретный порт, например:

```
udp::socket socket{ service, udp::endpoint{udp::v4(), 9997 } };
```

Тут же после этой команды вызывается брандмаузер, и если там проставить галочки, то у друга1 всё работает. Почему не брандмауэр не вызывается с рандомным портом?
Как это контролировать?

Comment: ...потому что у него не сделан port forwarding, как вы сделали у себя? Без знания связности между машинами по сети это игра в угадайку.

Comment: А как например скайп автоматически делает форвардинг?
Мы же вручную не форвардим порты для каждого приложения которое должно общаться с сервером

Comment: Или я чего-то не понимаю в документации, или ваш код в принципе не может работать. На клиенте вы не делаете `socket.connect(server_ep)` - куда в таком случае клиент шлёт данные? А на сервере вызов `socket.receive()` не должен срабатывать, он ведь только для сокетов с установленным соединением.

Comment: Ааа, да, забыл код перекопировать. (сорян) Там без конекта. и send_to вызывает. И сейчас, я уже немного другая проблема!!!Чувак помоги разобраться:

Когда я запилил в клиенте привязку к конкретному порту (в конструкторе сокета ) неожиданно выскочил виндвос брандмаузер. И когда друг1 поставил там галочки, и открыл в 2 раз программу. всё заработало!!!. Так вот, почему, если в конструкторе передать значение порта ноль, брандмаузер не предлагает проставить галочки?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, все эти детали в вопросе: [edit].

Comment: Написал детали в впопросе